# Mi código ignora el if

Tags: java, bucle-for, condiciones, while

Mi profesor nos dio un ejercicio donde tenemos que usar un *for* dentro de un *while*, pero necesitamos romper el *for* con un *if* porque las repeticiones se tenían que definir por el usuario. La cosa es que, mi código no ejecuta el *if*, simplemente lo ignora y sigue repitiendo el *for* una y otra vez por más que la condición se cumpla.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Aprendo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
        String SNnombre="si";
        String SNnota, N;
        int L, TL, M, TM, P;
        TL=P=TM=1;
        
        while (SNnombre == "si") { 
            System.out.print("Introduzca el nombre: "); 
            N=reader.nextLine();                  
            
            for(int i=1 ; i>-1 ;i++) {
                System.out.println("Notas de lengua: ");
                L=reader.nextInt();
                TL=TL+L;
                
                System.out.println("Notas de matematica: ");
                M=reader.nextInt();
                TM=TM+M;
                reader.nextLine();
                
                P++;
                
//aca es donde me da el problema

                System.out.println("Deseas seguir subiendo notas? si - no: ");
                SNnota=reader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(SNnota);
                if (SNnota == "no"){
                    i=-1;}
                }
            
            System.out.println("Deseas agregar otro nombre? si - no: \n");
            SNnombre=reader.nextLine(); 
            reader.nextLine();
            
        }reader.close();
        }}
```

Sé que no debería usar un *if* dentro del *for*, porque eso literalmente atenta contra el propósito del *for*, pero mi profesor dijo que no pongamos un *while* dentro del *for*, que encontremos la manera, y no la estoy encontrando.

Comment: Revisa: `(int i=1 ; i>-1 ;i++)` no se como trabajará java con un ciclo interminable, tal vez no lo ejecute ni una vez o lo ejecute por siempre hasta que hagas un cierre forzado.
Parece que es la primera opción si no se ejecuta el "if"

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa es una forma de usar el for cuando quieres un bucle infinito hasta que alguna condición finalice el for, talves su profesor asi lo pidió

Answer (score 2):

Te comento los errores encontrados en tu código:

Tus variables `TL` y `TM` tienes que inicializar a 0 porque son acumuladores, aunque en tu programa sólo están sumando las notas ingresadas pero no lo muestras.

Para comparar cadena se usa el método equal() de la clase String

```
if (SNnota.equals("no")
```

Está bien lo que haces después de leer un valor entero con Scanner agregues reader.nextLine();

```
System.out.println("Notas de matematica: ");
M=reader.nextInt();
TM=TM+M;
reader.nextLine();
```

Pero si lees un String no es necesario

```
 System.out.println("Deseas agregar otro nombre? si - no: \n");
 SNnombre=reader.nextLine(); 
 reader.nextLine(); //esto es innecesario
```

Para parar un bloque de código puedes usar `break`

```
 if (SNnota.equals("no"))break;
```

Entonces tu nuevo código quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Aprendo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
        String SNnombre="si";
        String SNnota, N;
        int L, TL=0, M, TM=0, P;
        TL=P=TM=1;
        
        while (SNnombre.equals("si")) { 
            System.out.print("Introduzca el nombre: "); 
            N=reader.nextLine();                  
            
            for(int i=1 ; i>-1 ;i++) {
                System.out.println("Notas de lengua: ");
                L=reader.nextInt();
                TL=TL+L;
                
                System.out.println("Notas de matematica: ");
                M=reader.nextInt();
                TM=TM+M;
                reader.nextLine();                
                P++;                
                //aca es donde me da el problema

                System.out.println("Deseas seguir subiendo notas? si - no: ");
                SNnota=reader.nextLine();                
                if (SNnota.equals("no"))break;
            }
            
            System.out.println("Deseas agregar otro nombre? si - no: \n");
            SNnombre=reader.nextLine();             
            if (SNnombre.equals("no"))break;
            
        }reader.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: si, las variables las inicializaba en 1 porque de daba un error by cero, así que estaba probando diferentes cosas para ver qué lo causaba, mi profe también había dicho que no debíamos usar un break, que busquemos otra forma, al final lo solucione cambiando los parámetros del for por (int i=100; i<=-1 ; i--) y también agregando cambiando los == por .equals

Comment: me hubiera servido tu respuesta igual si la hubiera visto antes :)

Answer (score 2):

para comparar cadenas debes utilizar "equals", especificamente yo recomiendo "equalsIgnoreCase", y para detener el for debes usar "break".
La sección de tu código que indicas quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
if("no".equalsIgnoreCase(SNnota)) { // Compara lo ingresado
    break; // Detiene el for.
}
```

Aqui una prueba:

[image: Debug]

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que le estas asignando el valor de -1 al i cuando respondes que "no", pero al volver arriba en el for aumenta su valor i++ (-1+1=0) y terminas con la condición de 0>-1, por eso te continua el ciclo.